# Building with Address Sanitizer on Android but with CMake

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to build a .so for android and I want to build with address sanitizer but the only instructions I see are for Android NDK based Makefiles, but I am using the newer endorsed CMake setup. Just adding the flag -fsanitize=address wasn't enough as the clang runtime library was missing.

what is the correct thing to add in my CMakeLists for Android built libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to prepare your device as described in [documentation](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerOnAndroid). You have to run `asan_device_setup` script from NDK. It will put asan .so on the device.